# Words belong to the first and second declension at the same time

Tags: adjective, declension

*[Exter](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exter#Latin)*, *magnus*, *diduus*, they all belong to the first declension and also the second declension.

Why these adjectives are so special?

Comment: I'm curious—why do you call them special? The majority of Latin adjectives act this way.

Answer (score 4):

This is, perhaps surprisingly, how the vast majority of Latin adjectives work!

In general, there are two types of Latin adjectives: "first-second" and "third". These are all "first-second" adjectives, which take first-declension endings in the feminine, and second-declension endings everywhere else.

Note that this is based on the noun's gender, not its own declension: *qvercus magna* (f), *nauta magnus* (m), *vulgus magnum* (n).